# Can't get the certain item using selector

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml

How can I only get the article and nothing else using css selector from the elements available in the below link. I would like to use this selector in my parser written in python.

I tried like:

```
div.user-review p
```

Using the above selector I get other things as well which I don't want. I want only the article.

Here is the link leading to the elements containing the article:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/readzjpl0bca3zr/Elements.txt?dl=0"

Comment: What do you mean "get to the article"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below CSS selector and let me know if it doesn't fetch desired output:

```
div.user-review p.lnhgt ~p
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your kind response. It throws the following error:     'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "~p"

Comment: But "div.user-review p.lnhgt" it does. I got the insight from you. Btw, very much willing to know what "~p" does this mean sir?

Comment: `~node` means [*general sibling selector*](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). `~p` should match all following siblings paragraphs of `p.lnhgt`